How to extend an interface with another interface depending on a property's type?
I want to be able to add additional constraints/types to my interface when a union type property is a particular value. Is this possible in Typescript?
So as a concrete example... If I have a type TypographyProps and it has a variant property in it of a union type. How can I use that variant property to extend the TypographyProps to include another type?
export interface TypographyProps extends ParentProps {
  variant?: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "p" | "span";
  color?: keyof Theme["colors"];
  spacing?: Theme["spacing"];
  wrap?: boolean;
}

// How can I add in the type def for each type `JSX.IntrinsicElements["h2"]`, etc... based on `variant`?


Can be done using generics. You have to create type based on Variant. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApyhcqoHsAOAzsgN4BQZAvhWAJ74oBqGwc4yAvMsgEQAWARh7IAPrz4AmYWP4Bmab3wKehfGx4BuGvRQBJcFFCFgCAKIAbCAFssYYlwBKEBLigATADzNDbMABpkQjBDEABzAD4tMggAD3xXMGRQSFhEFAAVelxQqDh8PlocAkIvZFjIEDdib1Z2cLKYiqq0DFsiolIybgA3Fl8AfgAuZEYtbgB3XPwh5AAjXFxLNjHkNwgYYf1goxMLa1tCAG1+KQBdKiA Does this help you? If yes i will post an answer

It may be possible using this approach but I need the definition of TypographyProps to be extended with those IntrinsicElements[varient]. So for example if someone passed in the varient "label" then the type would include the for attribute because I would be able to extend it with JSX.IntrinsicElements['label']

I ended up going with this solution. It is very similar to Tushar Shahi's answer above but I needed to be more explicit with strings in each type rather than create a new Variant type that has everything.
type HeadingVariantProps = {
  variant: "heading" | "subheading" | "title" | "subtitle";
  ref?: Ref<HTMLHeadingElement>;
};

type BodyVariantProps = {
  variant: "body";
  ref?: Ref<HTMLParagraphElement>;
};

type DefaultVariantProps = {
  variant?: undefined;
  ref?: Ref<HTMLSpanElement>;
};

export type TypographyProps = ParentProps & {
  color?: keyof Theme["colors"];
  spacing?: Theme["spacing"];
  wrap?: boolean;
} & (HeadingVariantProps | BodyVariantProps | DefaultVariantProps);


So you want to extend your interface to have additional keys. But the thing is an interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.
Checkout this blog
We can not do something like:
type Example =
  | { a: string }
  | {
      b: string;
    };
 
interface Foo extends Example { //Error
  c: string;
}

But we can do it using types:
type Example =
  | { a: string }
  | {
      b: string;
    };
 
type Foo = Example & {
  c: string;
};

Playground
Your use case is achievable using types and generics combined.
What we want is to pass a Variant and dynamically extend our type to add keys according to that variant.
Use keyof to read all the keys of JSX.IntrinsicElements['label']
interface ParentProps {}

type Variant = 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'p' | 'span';

type IntrinsicElements = Record<Variant, string>;

type TypographyProps<V extends Variant>  = {
  variant?: V;
  wrap?: boolean;
} & { [K in keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements[V]] : string }; 

Stackblitz

Thank you this is great! I'm having to constrain my prop's type when I return it, is that expected or is there a way around it?
if (props.variant === "h1") { return <h1 {...(props as IntrinsicElements["h1"])}>{props.children}</h1>; }

You mean something like this?
type Variant =  "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "p" | "span";
// alternatively:
// type Variant = keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;

export interface TypographyProps<V extends Variant > extends ParentProps {
  variant?: V;
  def: JSX.IntrinsicElements[V];
}


I need to add additional keys so this won't work for my specific use case but is nice to know the approach - thank you for posting.
